Solana RPC Node and Turbine Tree
Im reading Helius' blog post, Turbine: Block Propagation on Solana, and it lead to a couple questions.
The blog states, "The root node aggregates all active validators into a list, which is then sorted based on the stake each validator has in the network. Validators with higher stake-weight are prioritized to receive shreds sooner, enabling them to respond with their own vote messages for consensus faster."
In this context, is an RPC node consider an active validator (meaning it is included in the turbine tree)? I am assuming the answer to this question is yes, otherwise how would blocks be propagated to it?
Can a RPC node have stake so it can be prioritized to receive shreds sooner?

An RPC node is considered as a validator, even if it doesn't have any stake delegated to it. So you've got it all correct: the RPC node receives shreds, but it will not be a priority target for the leader.
It's possible to delegate stake to an RPC node, but it's considered an antipattern. It takes an RPC node a lot of resources to service requests, which means that it may not be able to keep up with the network and vote well.
The better option is to setup some form of stake-weighted quality-of-service between a validator with stake and an RPC node: https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/stake-weighted-qos
To go along with that, you can configure your staked voting validator to send all shreds directly to the RPC node.

Thank you for your reply. I went through the code and found this. So I don't think the RPC node actually receives shreds.

I think you're misinterpreting one particular line of code. RPC nodes do receive shreds -- how else do they receive data about transactions and keep their internal account state up to date in order to service queries?

That was my initial thought as well, but the nodes can receive data about transactions via gossip.

Turbine is the mechanism through which nodes receive processed transactions, and gossip does not handle that.

Are you sure gossip does not handle that? Here and here are references that seem to contradict your statement and show that shreds can be shared via gossip.
How am I misinterpreting the line of code I linked above? It is pretty clear in that line of code that nodes with zero stake are being filtered out. Do you have a reference that confirms that RPC nodes with zero stake are still included in the turbine tree?

These are for duplicate shreds, which are proofs that shreds for a duplicate block on the same slot have been provided. The gossip protocol propagates these to the network so that they can avoid trying to process duplicate blocks on the same slot.

The code that you referenced earlier takes TVU peers right before adding all staked nodes. The RPC nodes are part of that set.

I see, thank you for taking the time to engage in this discussion and educate me.
